# How can I implement static 'test local' data in an NUnit test?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a couple thousand NUnit tests for a library, many of which rely on having some statically available 'request context' that is scoped to the request being served and flows across tasks. The library consumer provides an implementation to retrieve the current request context.

I need to implement something to provide this context for our NUnit test project, where the context is scoped to each individual test run; each test run should have it's own object, and I should be able to access it from anywhere during the test.

Initially, I had achieved this using `TestContext.Current.Properties` and storing my request context there, but with a recent NUnit update, `Properties` has become read-only.

Is there any replacement that I can use to achieve 'test local' data? i.e. something that's scoped to the current test run, and statically accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Similar issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2760) on github contains the following statement from NUnit developer:

> However, it's not intended that you should change the properties of an
>   NUnit Test, because Test and its derivatives are internal and the
>   implementation can change. The internal classes allow it because
>   custom attributes may need to do it, but I recommend that tests avoid
>   doing it.

And such implementation change has actually happen. Before NUnit 2.6.0, `TestContext` had `Properties` bag, but since 2.6.0 it was moved to `TestAdapter`. You still could access it via `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties` however you have no guarantee that this will not change again in the future.

The cleaner way to implement such context accessor is by adding simple holder that will compare current test against the test for which current context instance was created. If those tests do not match it just creates a new context instance and remember current test.

Here is a working sample:

```
internal static class ContextAccessor
{
    private static TestExecutionContext currentRequestTest;

    private static RequestContext currentRequestContext;

    public static RequestContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            var currTest = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext;

            if (currentRequestTest == currTest)
            {
                return currentRequestContext;
            }

            currentRequestContext = CreateRequestContext();
            currentRequestTest = currTest;

            return currentRequestContext;
        }
    }

    public static RequestContext CreateRequestContext()
    {
        return new RequestContext();
    }
}
```

`RequestContext` here is your context class. `CreateRequestContext()` is basically a factory method that creates context. You could put any logic you need for creating new context instance.

Now in the test you could just call `ContextAccessor.Current`:

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    var context1 = ContextAccessor.Current;
    var context2 = ContextAccessor.Current;

    Assert.AreSame(context1, context2);
}
```

[**Sample Project on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q49683601-NUnit-Test-Data)